# Increment specific value of element in a 2d array JS

Tags: javascript

How can I create the starting positon on a coordinate plot and update (increment) the x value? Initially, `position` was given values of `2` and `5`, but for testing purposes, I'd just like to update the x value by 1, but am getting the same values returned?

```
function boardCreate(rows, columns) {
    for (let x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
            boardCell(x, y); 
        }
    }
}

function boardCell(x, y) {
    board[x] = board[x] || [];
    board[x][y] = x + " " + y;
}

var board = [];
boardCreate(10, 10);

let position = board[2][5];

function incrementX(position) {
    position[1] = position[1] + 1;
    return position;
}

incrementX(position);

console.log(position);
```

Comment: Where do you call your `incrementX()` function?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that in my edits. I've just included - doesn't work with it included

Comment: In Javascript, primitives (strings, numbers, etc) are passed by value, and copied.Your position is not the string object of board[2][5]

Comment: Why are you storing the x and y values in a single cell anyhow? You could retrieve them using the position of a cell inside the array. Nevertheless - you're question ain't too clear. Can you show what the array looks like initially and how it should like after you've incremented something?

Comment: Set an object to board[x][y] = {val: "whatever"}. then the object is set to positrion correctly

Comment: You do NOT change the value of `position` since it's masked by a local variable inside function and you do not re-assign it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to increment the board coordinates based on the `x` and `y` values of the current `position` - this can be achieved by:

1. extracting the `x` and `y` values at the specified `position`

   `const [x, y] = position.split(' ');`
2. incrementing `x` by one:

   `const nextX = Number.parseInt(x) + 1;`
3. reading the new position value from new `x` value and exisiting `y`

   `return board[nextX][y]`

Hope this helps!

```js
function boardCreate(rows, columns) {
  for (let x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
      boardCell(x, y);
    }
  }
}

function boardCell(x, y) {
  board[x] = board[x] || [];
  board[x][y] = x + " " + y;
}

var board = [];
boardCreate(10, 10);

let position = board[2][5];

function incrementX(position) {

  /* Ensure valid position specified before attempting increment */
  if (!position) {
    return;
  }

  /* Read x,y coordinates from array value */
  const [x, y] = position.split(' ');

  /* Parse x to number and increment it */
  const nextX = Number.parseInt(x) + 1;

  if (nextX >= board.length) {
    console.error(`next x: ${ nextX } out of bounds`);
    return;
  }

  /* Look up board value at next x, and same y coordinate */
  return board[nextX][y]
}


console.log(position);

/* Testing */
let p = incrementX(position);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  p = incrementX(p);
  console.log(p);
}
```